# Regex for matching text followed by text until closed bracket except matching opening bracket

Tags: regex, regex-recursion

Sorry if question is confusion.
From below text

```
value = ( select max( tbl.column_name ) from table tbl where trim(colum2)='value1'
and (trim((colum3)))='value3')
```

I want output below

```
select max( tbl.column_name ) from table tbl where trim(colum2)='value1'
    and (trim((colum3)))='value3'
```

basically starting from select max( till ) except ) is matching a opening bracket.

```
(select[ ]*max[ ]*\(.*column_name[ ]*\)[^)]*)
```

This matches only  till trim(colum2
Need help to escape bracket ) is there is a opening bracket including any nested

Thanks

Edit:
I finally did it java as shown below. But would like to know REGEX solution

```
String sql = readFile(file.getPath());
Pattern patTabs = Pattern.compile("(\\([ \n]*SELECT[ \n]*MAX[ \n]*\\(.*COLUMN_NAME[ \n]*\\))", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
Matcher tabMat = patTabs.matcher(sql);
while (tabMat.find()) {
    int i = tabMat.start();
    int j = tabMat.end();
    int l = 0;
    for (j = tabMat.end(); j < sql.length(); j++) {
        char k = sql.charAt(j);
        if (k == '(') {
            l++;
        }
        if (k == ')') {
            if (l == 0) {
                break;
            } else {
                l--;
            }
        }
    }
    System.out.println(sql.substring(i, j + 1))
}
```

Comment: Is there a carriage return after `'value1'`?

Comment: yes. looking for multiline pattern and multiple matches in a text file. but a single line solution is also ok. i can work on it

Comment: At quick glance something like `(select[ ]*max[ ]*\(.*column_name[ ]*\).*[\n]*.*')\)` might work.

Comment: Is it enough just to take everything between the first ( and the last ) ? So from `value = (any text)` it returns `any text`? Then use `^.*?\((.*)\)` and take group 1

Comment: I need sections only with this pattern select[ ]*max[ ]*\(.*column_name[ ]*\) till end of this query. So my main issue is ignore any ) if there is matching ( before that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll have to replace the line terminators with a whitespace in those expressions if you want a elegant solution. So you'll need to change this-

```sql
value = ( select max( tbl.column_name ) from table tbl where trim(colum2)='value1'
and (trim((colum3)))='value3')
```

to this-

```sql
value = ( select max( tbl.column_name ) from table tbl where trim(colum2)='value1' and (trim((colum3)))='value3')
```

**Edited**: Afterwards, you can use `\( *?(select *?max\( .*?column_name *?\).+) *?\)` to match the expression you expect to.

Here's a [live demo](https://regex101.com/r/1h8Tdm/3)

If you REALLY don't want to replace the line terminator in the expression and instead want to work with

```sql
value = ( select max( tbl.column_name ) from table tbl where trim(colum2)='value1'
and (trim((colum3)))='value3')
```

you *may* use this `\([ \n]*?(select[ \n]*?max\([ \n].*?column_name[ \n]\)[\D\d \n]+)[ \n]*?\)`. But I highly recommend against so, because if you feed in multiple `value = ( select..... )` to the same pattern, it will not work.

Here's a [live demo](https://regex101.com/r/1h8Tdm/2)

Comment: hi, thanks for the answer. but i need sections only with this pattern select[ ]*max[ ]*\(.*column_name[ ]*\) till end of this query

Comment: @Siva I edited the answer, is that what you wanted? Keep in mind, the line terminator in the expression must be replaced for efficiency